# How to import a excel when it is in protective mode?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to import my excel file to VBA script.For that i wrote a code and it works me fine.

```
   Dim XL As excel.Application
   Dim WBK As excel.Workbook
   Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   XL.Visible = False
   Set WBK = XL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\10000\excel.xlsx")
   Set osht = WBK.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

I am searching for a string and did some operation.But when the Excel is in protective mode or disabled for editing meant i can't able to get any data from excel file .Please help me or guide me to solve my Issue.
Thankz in advance....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Protected view is a working mode of Excel to reduce the risks, If we query Excel data from SQL Server side, it will not affect the process. Based on the current information, please make sure you have installed Microsoft Access Database Engine, open SQL Server Management Studio and check whether “Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0” lists under “Linked Server”, “Provider” folder. And then try to select data from the Excel file again. For example:

```
select * from openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\your_path_here\worksheetTest.xlsx','select * from [Sheet1$]');
```